# Concatenating in selector

Tags: javascript

I expected that selector will be `$("a.3")` but it was not.

```
var giftId = '3';
$("a."+giftId).click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Can not I make like this?

Even if class name is not starts with digit it still does not concatenated

```
<a class="gift6"...

    var giftId = '6'; 
    $("a.gift"+giftId).click(...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have classes which start with a number, which would explain  why this isn't working.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they **cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Comment: ok, what about this `var giftId = '6'; $("a.gift:"+giftId).click(... ` ? this still does not concatenated and class name not started with digit

Comment: @thinker `6` isn't a valid pseudo class so you can't do that

Comment: @thinker I would suggest having a data attribute on your element, `data-giftid` and then you can do: `$("a.gift[data-giftid=" + giftId + "]")`